# Visual Studio 2008 > Application debugging disabled

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

today my VS2008 started to have a strange behaviour... I usually work wit web sites (not web project) and when I need to debug I attach the debugger to the w3wc.exe process.

But today when I attach the process I get a kind of toolbox on the solution explorer, as you can see from this screenshot

http://i45.tinypic.com/a0ggmw.jpg

(sorry, I can't post images yet)

I still put breakpoints but they're ignored. Do you know what happened?

tnx
d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. In my Solution there are:

- a web site
- a project
- another project
- yet another project

the web site had a dll of "yet another project", but it was copied manually, the web site had not the reference to "yet another project". So I modified the sources of "yet another project" and since that moment I wasn't able to debug.

Solution: I've deleted the DLL and added the reference to "yet another project", now I can attach w3wp.exe and use the debugger.